# Set inner HTML using QDomDocument

Tags: qt, dom, qwebelement

How can I set the inner HTML in a QDomElement?

When I’m using QWebElement I have the method [QWebElement::setInnerXml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebelement.html#setInnerXml), there is some similar method in QDomElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API to "inject" XML snippets as text into a QDomDocument (or QXmlStreamWriter). One has to use the API and create the nodes programmatically.

Comment: This being said, it is sad that they do not offer such a function in Qt DOM. After all, you often end up having to do that and they have the "perfect" parser already written and accessible from within...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a string to start with, my current solution is to generate a DOM tree from it, import that tree in a fragment, then copy those in the right place (you must have an import which is why you need an intermediate fragment. Quite unfortunate if you ask me.)

```
// assuming that 'n' is the node you are replacing or at least inserting after
// 'parent' is the parent of 'n'
// 'result' is the string to replace 'n' or insert after 'n'
QDomDocument doc_text("snap");
doc_text.setContent("<text>" + result + "</text>", true, NULL, NULL, NULL);
QDomDocumentFragment frag(xml.createDocumentFragment());
frag.appendChild(xml.importNode(doc_text.documentElement(), true));
QDomNodeList children(frag.firstChild().childNodes());
const int max(children.size());
QDomNode previous(n);
for(int i(0); i < max; ++i)
{
    QDomNode l(children.at(0));
    parent.insertAfter(children.at(0), previous);
    previous = l;
}
// if you are replacing, then delete node n as well
parent.removeChild(n);
```

Note that the <text> tag is used so that way result does not need to be a tag, it could just be text and it will still work.

Obviously, if you have a fragment or XML from another document to start with, ignore the code that creates that code in the doc_text object.